# Getting RGB values from YUV_420_888 image

Tags: android, rgb, yuv

I am trying to crop out the center square portion of a camera preview YUV_420_888 image. I want to get the RGB values as I process each frame instead of converting to bitmap and getting then getting the values.

Here is what I currently have but I can't seem to get a valid image. I think I am retrieving the YUV values incorrectly.

```
planes: plane0 pixelStride:1 rowStride:1280 height:720 capacity:921600
planes: plane1 pixelStride:2 rowStride:1280 height:719 capacity:460799
planes: plane2 pixelStride:2 rowStride:1280 height:719 capacity:460799
```

_

```
fun processImage(image: Image) {
    val imageSize = 224
    val subImageWidth = imageSize/2
    val subImageHeight = imageSize/2

    val bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(imageSize * imageSize * 3 * 4)
    bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())

    val plane0 = image.planes[0]
    val plane1 = image.planes[1]
    val plane2 = image.planes[2]

    val width = plane0.rowStride
    val height = plane0.buffer.capacity() / plane0.rowStride

    //Documentation says that plane 1&2 will have the same pixel stride and row stride
    val plane12Width = plane1.rowStride / plane1.pixelStride

    val xOffset = (width - subImageWidth) / 2
    val yOffset = (height - subImageHeight) / 2

    for (y in 0 until imageSize) {
        for (x in 0 until imageSize) {
            val yb = plane0.buffer[(x + xOffset) + width * (y + yOffset)]
            val ub = plane1.buffer[(x + xOffset)/2 + plane12Width * (y + yOffset)]
            val vb = plane2.buffer[(x + xOffset)/2 + plane12Width * (y + yOffset)]

            val rgb = yuvToRGB(yb, ub, vb)


            bb.putFloat(rgb[0])
            bb.putFloat(rgb[1])
            bb.putFloat(rgb[2])
        }
    }
    imageView.setBitmap(getOutputImage(bb))
}

fun yuvToRGB(y: Float, u: Float, v: Float): FloatArray {
    val rgb = FloatArray(3)

    val rTemp = ((y - 16) * 1.164 + (v - 128) * 1.596).toFloat()
    val gTemp = ((y - 16) * 1.164 - (u - 128) * 0.392 - (v - 128) * 0.813).toFloat()
    val bTemp = ((y - 16) * 1.164 + (u - 128) * 2.017).toFloat()

    if (rTemp > 255f) {
        rgb[0] = 255f
    } else if (rTemp < 0f) {
        rgb[0] = 0f
    } else {
        rgb[0] = rTemp
    }

    if (gTemp > 255f) {
        rgb[1] = 255f
    } else if (gTemp < 0f) {
        rgb[1] = 0f
    } else {
        rgb[1] = gTemp
    }

    if (bTemp > 255f) {
        rgb[2] = 255f
    } else if (bTemp < 0f) {
        rgb[2] = 0f
    } else {
        rgb[2] = bTemp
    }

    return rgb
}

private fun getOutputImage(output: ByteBuffer): Bitmap {
    val imageSize = 224
    output.rewind() // Rewind the output buffer after running.

    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageSize, imageSize, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    val pixels = IntArray(imageSize * imageSize) // Set your expected output's height and width
    for (i in 0 until imageSize * imageSize) {
        val a = 0xFF
        val r: Float = output.float
        val g: Float = output.float
        val b: Float = output.float
        pixels[i] = a shl 24 or (r.toInt() shl 16) or (g.toInt() shl 8) or b.toInt()
    }
    bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, imageSize, 0, 0, imageSize, imageSize)

    return bitmap
}
```

[image: center crop]

Comment: What does the picture represent? Good output/bad output? Where is it coming from?

Comment: The image is discolored. I can see the outlines of the image. I can post an image.

Comment: I'm not understanding this, so you should probably do that.

Comment: Updated post with new image and how we are constructing the bitmap image for the small preview

Comment: So, the yellow inset indicates the data you want to process as RGB. Your problem is that the colors are all wrong. Otherwise, the size & positioning are valid. Is that correct?

Comment: I still have no idea what the significance of the blue & green picture is.

Comment: Size and positioning is fine. You can see the outline of the wire in the yellow image. This is taking out a center portion of the screen.

Comment: Yes, I can see the outline, but I'm not sure why you've mentioned that. _Your problem is the colors, correct?_

Comment: Yes. The colors are wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207309/discussion-between-greeble31-and-ddukesterman).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Fix #1:**

You want to be sure you're hitting the correct area of the color plane(s), for the UV values:

```
val ub = plane1.buffer[((x + xOffset)/2) * 2 + plane1.rowStride * ((y + yOffset)/2)].toFloat()
val vb = plane1.buffer[((x + xOffset)/2) * 2 + 1 + plane1.rowStride * ((y + yOffset)/2)].toFloat()
```

I've intentionally used `plane1` for both as sort of a hack. With your particular device, these `Images` are coming out with *interleaved* color planes. `plane1` and `plane2` are *essentially* the same array (some caveats). They both "point" to the same area in RAM; they are 99.9% overlapped. And they contain values like this: "U/V/U/V/U/V", which is why `pixelStride` is two. I think it would also work if you did this:

```
val ub = plane1.buffer[((x + xOffset)/2) * 2 + plane1.rowStride * ((y + yOffset)/2)].toFloat()
val vb = plane2.buffer[((x + xOffset)/2) * 2 + plane2.rowStride * ((y + yOffset)/2)].toFloat()
```

...because apparently the `ByteBufferDirect` interface has abstracted away the fact that `plane2` starts 1 byte to the right of `plane1` (in native memory). (Things would look slightly different if you were doing this on the native side, from JNI.)

The `((x + xOffset)/2)*2` correction is to account for this interleaving, and the `pixelStride`. The `((y + yOffset)/2)` correction is to account for the fact that every other pixel row is skipped during the 4:2:0 subsampling process. (Every other *column* is skipped, as well, but because each pixel consists of 2 bytes (U,V) next to each other, we need to double the offset back up with the `* 2`. Integer math; we're trying to make an even number, so the reference offset is always on a "U").

**Fix #2:**

In this area:

```
val r: Float = output.float * 255
val g: Float = output.float * 255
val b: Float = output.float * 255
```

...you don't want to multiply by 255, because your values are already in the range 0..255.

**Fix #3:**

As you noted, the array values are being interpreted as "signed"; your conversion algorithm expects this to be unsigned, so it's best to have them in the range 0..255.

**Recommended Improvement**

It would be more efficient if `yuvToRGB()` used an integral data type for both input & output, instead of `floats`.